# ScriptableObject does not show up in Inspector when Unity is closed and then reopened

Tags: unity-game-engine

Like title,I didn't create a custom inspector for ScriptableObject,and I googled, most of the answers are using SetDirty(object) but it did't work.When I modify any of the code in the project and Unity will refactor the C# code, some of the ScriptableObjects will be displayed in the Inspector panel,not all SOs are displayed but partially displayed，I checked these displayed SOs,data is not lost;When I reopen the project again,and then click SO in Project panel,Inspector panel has nothing;
[image]
[image]

as you can see, MouseModuleData is not display which is created from last time i opened Unity，MouseModuleData1 is created from this time;So I think if there is a problem with my data structure.

```
/// <summary>
/// Base Class of Module Data
/// </summary>
public abstract class PitchModuleBaseData : ScriptableObject, IEnumerable
{
    public abstract IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}

/// <summary>
/// Face Module Data
/// </summary>
[System.Serializable, CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "MouseModuleData", menuName = "AvatarData/MouseModuleData")]
public class MouthModuleData : PitchModuleBaseData
{
    public BoneData MouthCornerLeft;
    public BoneData MouthCornerRight;
    public BoneData LeapUp;
    public BoneData LeapMiddle;
    public BoneData LeapDown;
    public BoneData MouseRoot;

    public MouthModuleData()
    {
        MouthCornerLeft = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_CornerL, PitchFaceConst.Mouth_CornerR);
        MouthCornerRight = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_CornerR, PitchFaceConst.Mouth_CornerL);
        LeapDown = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_LeapDown);
        LeapMiddle = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_LeapMiddle);
        LeapUp = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_LeapUp);
        MouseRoot = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Mouth_Root);
    }

    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        BoneData[] arr = new BoneData[6];
        arr[0] = MouthCornerLeft;
        arr[1] = MouthCornerRight;
        arr[2] = LeapUp;
        arr[3] = LeapDown;
        arr[4] = MouseRoot;
        arr[5] = LeapMiddle;
        return new DataEnumerator(arr);
    }
}
```

So I did a test; I created a data like the one above.

```
 public abstract class ABData : ScriptableObject, IEnumerable
{
    public abstract IEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}

[System.Serializable, CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "TestData", menuName = "Create/TestData")]
public class TestData : ABData
{
    public TestData()
    {
        data = new BoneData();
        Middle = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_Mid);
        Left = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_Left, PitchFaceConst.Eye_Right);
        Right = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_Right, PitchFaceConst.Eye_Left);
        EyeLeft1 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_L1, PitchFaceConst.Eye_R1);
        EyeLeft2 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_L2, PitchFaceConst.Eye_R2);
        EyeLeft3 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_L3, PitchFaceConst.Eye_R3);
        EyeLeft4 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_L4, PitchFaceConst.Eye_R4);
        EyeRight1 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_R1, PitchFaceConst.Eye_L1);
        EyeRight2 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_R2, PitchFaceConst.Eye_L2);
        EyeRight3 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_R3, PitchFaceConst.Eye_L3);
        EyeRight4 = new BoneData(PitchFaceConst.Eye_R4, PitchFaceConst.Eye_L4);
    }

    public BoneData data;

    public BoneData Middle;
    public BoneData Left;
    public BoneData Right;

    public BoneData EyeLeft1;
    public BoneData EyeLeft2;
    public BoneData EyeLeft3;
    public BoneData EyeLeft4;

    public BoneData EyeRight1;
    public BoneData EyeRight2;
    public BoneData EyeRight3;
    public BoneData EyeRight4;

    public override IEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then let me go crazy, something happened.TheTestData is Showed as normal Whether it is reopened or not, it works just like a normal OS.

[image]

Please help me, let me get on the right track.

Comment: I see the script is lost, may be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
I put all ScriptableObject code in one .cs file, After reload the project,Unity can't find the  ScriptableObject script instanceID,you can let Inspector to DEBUG mode to check! 
The answer is every ScriptableObject you should have a reference .cs file with it along;

Comment: In general it is allways way batter and cleaner to have one `.cs` file for **each** individual class, struct, enum, etc definition! First of all because it is way easier to find your individual types than and second a file/type you didn't change doesn't have to get recompiled -> if you have **all** your implementation in one single file it has to recompile the entire file every time you make a small change in one of the definitions!!